How to create universal failure handler for callbacks with different signatures
How do I write a reasonable type for failWrapper below, so the final definition of handlers doesn't have typescript errors?
type StringCallback = (s: string) => 'foo'
type NumberCallback = (n: number) => 42

type Handlers = {
  onstring: StringCallback
  onnumber: NumberCallback
}

const failWrapper = (cb: StringCallback | NumberCallback) => 
  (x: Parameters<typeof cb>[0]) => {
    try {
      return cb(x)
    } catch {
      console.log('caught!')
    }
    throw new Error()
  }

const stringCallback: StringCallback = s => 'foo'
const numberCallback: NumberCallback = n => 42

const handlers: Handlers = {
  onstring: failWrapper(stringCallback),
  onnumber: failWrapper(numberCallback)
}

I've tried using various generics including inferring the types, but I haven't managed to come up with anything that works.
The snippet above is available on the TypeScript playground.

A truly universal failWrapper is easy enough to write, by making it generic in the argument and return types, as shown in this playground link. That's how I'd recommend you proceed, unless you have some need for making it only accept specifically StringCallback or NumberCallback (in which case you should [edit] to state that reason in the question). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?
